# Create a regex for finding comma-separated strings without repeating the central part

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that matches ALL OF and ONLY the following strings `boo`, `foo`, `tar`, `boo,foo`, `boo,tar`, `foo,tar`, `foo,boo`, `tar,boo`, `tar,foo`, `boo,foo,tar`, `boo,tar,foo`, `tar,boo,foo`, `tar,foo,boo`, `foo,boo,tar` and `foo,tar,boo`.

(Strings that repeat themselves such as `boo,boo` or `boo,boo,tar` are NOT GOOD)

**Plus: I need the Regular Expression itself to contain the strings `boo`, `foo` and `tar` only once each.**

So, to recap: I want no repetition both in the matched strings and the regEx itself.

Any way to achieve this result?

this is what I have so far `(boo|foo|tar)((,)(boo|foo|tar))*`

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this result.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far?

Comment: @ThomasSmyth  this is what I have so far, and I'm kind of lost after this :S   (boo|foo|tar)((,)(boo|foo|tar))*

Comment: Your attempt doesn't meet your own criteria of not repeating the words? Why insist on using a regex for this?

Comment: @rockstar yes, I know, my attempt is bad, that's why I'm asking the question, because I'm stuck /  regex because it needs to work with the Joi module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\1)(?:,(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\2))*$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pu7ktm/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(boo|foo|tar)` - matches either `boo` or `foo` or `tar` and capture it as group 1
- `(?!.*\1)` - Negative lookahead to make sure that whatever is stored in group 1 does not come anywhere else later in the string
- `(?:,(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\2))*`

  - `,(boo|foo|tar)` - matches a `,` followed by either `boo` or `foo` or `tar` and store it as group 2
  - `(?!.*\2)` - Negative lookahead to make sure that whatever is stored in group 2 does not come anywhere else later in the string
  - `*` - matches the above subsequences 0+ times
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

**Alternative Regex:**

[`^(?:,?(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pu7ktm/4)

Comment: It's pretty good, but do you think it's possible to avoid repeating `boo|foo|tar` more than once in the regEx?

Comment: @Emilio what do you mean? This regex does exactly what you want it to do. This is a great answer btw, never knew about negative lookaheads.

Comment: @chrisz: his requirements don't allow the words to appear in the regex more than once. IMO, he should be asking about how to solve the actual problem in the module he said he's using, since the demands of this question seem very odd.

Comment: @chrisz the part in bold in the question;  I will need to concatenate many strings together, I would prefer that "boo", "foo" and "tar" are not repeated more than once in the regEx itself.

Comment: @rockstar yes I know what requirements are pretty odd, but they come from a front-end I have no control on // and I need to make things clean

Comment: @Emilio Will this work for you [`^(?:,?(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pu7ktm/3)

Comment: @Emilio Please select it as the answer if it helped you

Comment: @Gurman can you explain the updated regex? Are you matching based on a previously found group?

Comment: @chrisz Yes. It first captures `foo` or `boo` or `tar` as group 1 and then checks that whatever is captures in group 1 is not present anywhere else in the string. The `*` in the end will repeat this whole pattern 0 or more times. Just a shorter version of my 1st solution. The only difference was because of the leading optional comma(`,`)

Comment: @Gurman I modified it a little bit to avoid matching `,boo` or `,boo,foo`  :  `^(?:(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\1)(,(?!$))?)*$`

Comment: @Emilio I think this would do the job [`^(?!,)(?:,?(boo|foo|tar)(?!.*\1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pu7ktm/5)